# Check for two values, if the overlap then check for their score and print the one with highest score in another file

Tags: text-processing, perl

I have a file, from which I have to take each query and check the Alt_from and Alt_to values. If the values of Alt_from and Alt_to overlap then check for the row with the highest score and print it in a file along with the non-overlapping values.

Input file:

```
Sr.No   query   score   ALIfrom ALIto
1        g1     135.2   93      231
2       g182    40.5    244     296
3       g182    45.4    247     311
4       g182    53.1    302     348
5       g182    50.6    305     362
6       g182    52.9    354     396
7       g182    24.9    357     397
8       g19     45.2    19      181
9       g19    166.8    19      208
10      g19    182.3    27      258
11      g22     94.5    46      139
12      g22    101.3    141     221
13      g22     66.7    230     353
14      g22     36.8    230     391
15     g266     57.7    47      127
16     g266     12.6    343     375
17     g266     17.8    348     375
```

Expected output:

```
Sr.No   query   score   ALIfrom ALIto
1        g1     135.2   93      231
2       g182    40.5    244     296
4       g182    53.1    302     348
6       g182    52.9    354     396
10      g19    182.3    27      258
11      g22     94.5    46      139
12      g22    101.3    141     221
13      g22     66.7    230     353
15     g266     57.7    47      127
17     g266     17.8    348     375
```

I tried using Perl but it does not check the correct overlapping values. What I mean by overlap is, for example in query g1 (Sr.no 2) range of Alt_from and Alt_to values is 150 to 200 and in query g1 (Sr.no 3) range of Alt_from and Alt_to values is 160 to 190. These values of Sr.no 3 falls within the range of values in Sr.no 2 this is overlap. In such a case the code should check for their score and take the ones with the highest score. As you can see in the expected output, the row with Sr.no 2 is removed because of low score and Sr.no 3 is taken as it has a higher score

Comment: What do you mean by values overlapping?

Comment: @SatōKatsura what I mean by overlap is, for example in query g1 (Sr.no 2) range of Alt_from and Alt_to values is 150 to 200 and in query g1 (Sr.no 3) range of Alt_from and Alt_to values is 160 to 190. These values of Sr.no 3 falls within the range of values in Sr.no 2 this is overlap. In such a case the code should check for their score and take the ones with the highest score. As you can see in the expected output, the row with Sr.no 2 is removed because of low score and Sr.no 3 is taken as it has a higher score.

Comment: How many rows can be in each query?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) include the information you added in the comments (comments are easy to miss and can be deleted without warning); ii) explain what you tried with Perl and how it failed.

Comment: @SatōKatsura It depends. Some query may have more than 5 rows and some may have only 1 row.

Comment: Which line do you output if you have three ranges, (1,2), (2,3), (3,4), with scores 1, 2 and 3, for one query? Does it depend on the ordering in the file?

Comment: @kusalananda (1,2)(2,3)(3,4) does not overlap.so those 3 values for one query will be taken. There is no unique order in the file. The file is same as the input i have provided.

Comment: @Hari Oh, I think you misunderstand my notation. With (1,2) I denote an entry with `ALIfrom=1` and `ALIto=2`. My question is basically whether the overlaps should only be considered in pairs, or in connected groups.

Comment: @kusalananda the overlap can be (1,6)(2,7) or (1,6)(2,5). If is there is no overlap.then the alifrom and alito be like (1,3)(3,4)(6,7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lightly tested Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $header = <>;
print $header;

my $query = '';
my @store = ();
LINE: while (<>) {
    my ( $line, %data );

    $line = $_;

    chomp;
    @data{qw/sr query score from to/} = split /\s+/;

    if ( $data{query} eq $query ) {
        for ( my $i = @store - 1 ; $i >= 0 ; $i-- ) {
            my %odata = %{ $store[$i]->[1] };
            if ( $odata{to} > $data{from} and $odata{from} < $data{to} ) {

                # overlap
                if ( $data{score} > $odata{score} ) { splice @store, $i, 1 }
                else                                { next LINE }
            }
        }
        push @store, [ $line, \%data ];
    }
    else {
        for (@store) { print $_->[0] }
        @store = ( [ $line, \%data ] );
        $query = $data{query};
    }
}
for (@store) { print $_->[0] }
```

Comment: @SatoKatsura This code is working partially. My actual file is huge and as it goes down the file it does not print the correct values.

Comment: @Hari It's working with the sample data you posted above. If you post an example of input data where it breaks I can try to fix it.

Comment: @Satokatsura I have updated the input data and the expected output.please advise.

Comment: @Hari I edited the script.  However I can't test it, since your sample data is inconsistent, f.i. line with serial 21 looks different in input and the required output.

Comment: @Satokatsura it's a mistake from my side. I have made the input and output file consistent. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: @Hari You specs are still not completely clear.  In your new example line 3 overtakes line 2 because of the score, and line 4 overtakes line 3 (again because of the score), but line 4 alone can't overtake line 2 because the values don't overlap.  You need to explain how these situations are resolved.  My script removes lines 2 and 3, but your sample data implies you want to keep line 2.

Comment: @Satokatsura it should take each query for example query: g182 have 6 results row wise. so when we check line 2 and 3, there is overlap because the ALifrom value is 244 and Alito value is 296 (line 2) and ALIfrom value is 247 and Alito value is 311(line 3). line 3 has high score than line 2. so it should print line3. In the code, you provided the output for the query 182 is line 4 and 6. it is not comparing line 2 and 3

Comment: @Satokatsura  also if I add two more column say target and description its showing error. Target and description values are alpha numeric. Thanks

Comment: @Hari As I explained above: it compares lines 2 and 3, and removes line 2.  Then it compares lines 3 and 4, and removes line 3.  That's why only line 4 is left.  If this is not what you want, you need to tell how to resolve this situation.  As for adding columns, there should be no reason for errors as long as you add them at the end (i.e. _after_ column 5).